How to fix Ollama 403 installation Error?
Hi I need to run Ollama on my Mac OS X but I can't install it using Ollama run llama3
I get the 403 error.
I am using v2ray on the Clash Verge client. But it seems my client cannot fully change my proxy and the terminal still gets my local IP and bans my access.
Is there any way I can change my proxy for the terminal?
by the way, when I hit the wifi icon in the menu bar holding the Option key the IP address and router are still set to my local. see the Screenshot.
how can I fix this? Is it my router or the network I use? Something is preventing me from fully changing my proxy. however, I have no problem with the websites I visit or the apps I use.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
